# Catching generic FaultException<T> thrown from IErrorHandler?

Tags: wcf, web-services

For a service, there is a group of faults which can be thrown by all operations, so in order to centralize that, I have made a behavior, `FaultAdderBehavior`, which adds fault contracts to all operations on a service. It seems to work fine as the contracts are added to the WSDL and the client can catch the fault with a line like:

```
...
catch(FaultException<MyFault> e){ ... }
...
```

I have also made an `IErrorHandler` which converts non-fault exceptions to a certain kind of fault. See below.
The problem is, that the fault which is constructed in the error handler cannot be caught on the client. That is, it cannot be caught as a *generic* `FaultException<MyFault>`, but only as `FaultException`.
If I explicitly adds a `FaultContract(typeof(MyFault))` to the operation, the client can suddenly catch the generic fault exception just fine.

So that could indicate that something is wrong with my `FaultAdderBehavior` after all. Or is there something wrong with my error handler?

I have noticed, that the `fault.Action` given as argument to `CreateMessage()` is null. This raises my concern.

Below is an example illustrating the problem. It is the method `ShouldThrowFault()` that causes headaches, while `ThrowsDirectly()` works exactly as desired.

To summarize, my question is: why can't the client catch the generic `FaultException<MyFault>` when it comes from the error handler?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUncatchableFaultService
{
  [OperationContract]
//    [FaultContract(typeof(MyFault))]
  void ShouldThrowFault(string arg1);  

  [OperationContract]
  void ThrowsDirectly();
}

[FaultAdderBehavior(typeof(MyFault), typeof(MyFault2))]
[MyErrorHandlerBehavior]
internal class UncatchableFaultService : IUncatchableFaultService
{
  public void ShouldThrowFault(string arg1)
  {
    throw new Exception();
  }

  public void ThrowsDirectly()
  {
    throw new FaultException<MyFault>(new MyFault());
  }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyFault
{
}

[DataContract]
public class MyFault2
{
}

public class MyErrorHandlerBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
  public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
  {
  }

  public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
  {
  }

  public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
  {
    foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase dispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
    {
      ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = dispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;
      if (channelDispatcher == null) continue;
      channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new MyErrorHandler());
    }
  }

  private class MyErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
  {

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message message)
    {
      if (error is FaultException) return;  

      var fault = new FaultException<MyFault>(new MyFault(), "I am a fault.");
      MessageFault messageFault = fault.CreateMessageFault();
      message = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, fault.Action);
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

public class FaultAdderBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
  private Type[] faults;

  public FaultAdderBehaviorAttribute(params Type[] faults)
  {
    this.faults = faults;
  }

  public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
  {
  }

  public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
  {
  }

  public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
  {
  }

  public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
  {
    foreach (OperationDescription op in contractDescription.Operations)
      foreach (Type fault in this.faults)
        op.Faults.Add(this.ExposeFault(fault));
  }

  private FaultDescription ExposeFault(Type fault)
  {
    string action = fault.Name;
    DescriptionAttribute attr = (DescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fault, typeof(DescriptionAttribute));

    if (attr != null) action = attr.Description;
    FaultDescription description = new FaultDescription(action);
    description.DetailType = fault;
    description.Name = fault.Name;
    return description;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with `FaultAdderBehaviorAttribute` and you are right to be worried that `fault.Action` is null.

For FaultException functionality to work properly you must have non-null actions for each fault.

When you declare the FaultContract on the operation itself you are implicitly using WCF's ability to automatically generate the action string ([further details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/02/05/actions-for-faultexceptions.aspx)). However, when you use your `FaultAdderBehaviorAttribute`, any default actions for declared operations have already been generated, and you are failing to provide a valid action.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the pointer to "further details"!